# Enable WiFi with SD card after first boot

Tags: wifi, boot, config.txt

I want to enable WiFi on Rasberry Pi from SD card. I already installed and used, so it isn't the first boot.

I search online and I found no answer to my problem

How can I enable on boot the WiFi after disabled from GUI. Maybe by adding some line to `boot/config.txt` in SD card.

I founded only answer to disable but nothing to enable (after disabling from GUI).

I can't access by ssh. I want to do from SD card.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have another computer/PC?

Comment: How did you disable and why?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Comment: It is disabled by default, by "Wi-Fi knockout" or some such named utility.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a wpa_supplicant.conf file like it is described in this article.

https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2017/04/manually-setting-up-pi-wifi-using-wpa_supplicant-conf/